# What is a profile diagram in UML?

Tags: uml

What is a profile diagram in UML? More specifically what is the role of this diagram? And what can we use it for (problems we can solve with it, or solutions we  can simplify more with it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [profile diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html) lets you define an extension to UML by defining your own stereotypes and a couple of other similar elements.  The idea is to tailor the expressivity of UML diagrams to a specific domain.

Here you can find [some examples](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-profile-diagram/), such as:

- enriching the class diagram with symbols or stereotypes that correspond to a framework (for example EJB components) or a method (for example the Boundary-Control-Entity design that is used to transform use cases in a systematic manner into a class diagram).
- adding stereotypes to allow to represent more precisely nodes of a deployment diagram according to a better network typology.
- adding tagged values to enrich diagrams with ownership, authorship, or configuration management information.